# Laravel Livewire abre el mismo modal varias veces

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire

Usando Laravel Livewire me he dado cuenta que los scripts entran en conflicto, cuando livewire hace algún cambio en el DOM veo que hay iconos que desaparecen, y al abrir el modal se abre varias veces. Como podría solucionar esto?

Este es la vista de mi componente:

```
<div>
    <h2 class="intro-y text-lg font-medium mt-10">
        Categorías
    </h2>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-6 mt-5">
        <div class="intro-y col-span-12 flex flex-wrap sm:flex-nowrap items-center mt-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary shadow-md mr-2" data-tw-toggle="modal"
                data-tw-target="#category-form-modal" wire:click='resetVariables()'>Crear nuevo</button>

            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropdown-toggle btn px-2 box" aria-expanded="false" data-tw-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="w-5 h-5 flex items-center justify-center"> <i class="w-4 h-4" data-lucide="plus"></i>
                    </span>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu w-40">
                    <ul class="dropdown-content">
                        <li>
                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item"> <i data-lucide="printer" class="w-4 h-4 mr-2"></i>
                                Print </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item"> <i data-lucide="file-text"
                                    class="w-4 h-4 mr-2"></i> Export to Excel </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item"> <i data-lucide="file-text"
                                    class="w-4 h-4 mr-2"></i> Export to PDF </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden md:block mx-auto text-slate-500">Mostrando 1 de {{ $total }} entradas</div>
            <div class="w-full sm:w-auto mt-3 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-auto md:ml-0">
                <div class="w-56 relative text-slate-500">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control w-56 box pr-10" placeholder="Search...">
                    <i class="w-4 h-4 absolute my-auto inset-y-0 mr-3 right-0" data-lucide="search"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- BEGIN: Data List -->
        <div class="intro-y col-span-12 overflow-auto lg:overflow-visible">
            <table class="table table-report -mt-2">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="whitespace-nowrap">IMAGEN</th>
                        <th class="whitespace-nowrap">NOMBRE</th>
                        <th class="whitespace-nowrap">DESCRIPCIÓN</th>
                        <th class="text-center whitespace-nowrap">ESTADO</th>
                        <th class="text-center whitespace-nowrap">ACCIONES</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @forelse ($categories as $category)
                        <tr class="intro-x">
                            <td class="w-40">
                                <div class="flex">
                                    <div class="w-10 h-10 image-fit zoom-in">
                                        <img alt="Midone - HTML Admin Template" class="tooltip rounded-full"
                                            src="dist/images/preview-1.jpg" title="Uploaded at 6 September 2020">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="text-slate-500 font-medium whitespace-nowrap mt-0.5">{{ $category->name }}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="text-slate-500 font-medium whitespace-nowrap mt-0.5">
                                    {{ $category->description }}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="w-40">
                                <div
                                    class="flex items-center justify-center  {{ $category->status ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger' }}">
                                    <i data-lucide="check-square" class="w-4 h-4 mr-2"></i>
                                    {{ $category->status ? 'Activo' : 'Inactivo' }}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="table-report__action w-56">
                                <div class="flex justify-center items-center">
                                    <a class="flex items-center mr-3" href="javascript:;"> <i data-lucide="check-square"
                                            class="w-4 h-4 mr-1"></i> Edit </a>
                                    <a class="flex items-center text-danger" href="javascript:;" data-tw-toggle="modal"
                                        data-tw-target="#delete-confirmation-modal"> <i data-lucide="trash-2"
                                            class="w-4 h-4 mr-1"></i> Delete </a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @empty
                    @endforelse
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- END: Data List -->
        <!-- BEGIN: Pagination -->
        <div class="intro-y col-span-12 flex flex-wrap sm:flex-row sm:flex-nowrap items-center">
            <nav class="w-full sm:w-auto sm:mr-auto">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="#"> <i class="w-4 h-4" data-lucide="chevrons-left"></i> </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="#"> <i class="w-4 h-4" data-lucide="chevron-left"></i> </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-item"> <a class="page-link" href="#">...</a> </li>
                    <li class="page-item"> <a class="page-link" href="#">1</a> </li>
                    <li class="page-item active"> <a class="page-link" href="#">2</a> </li>
                    <li class="page-item"> <a class="page-link" href="#">3</a> </li>
                    <li class="page-item"> <a class="page-link" href="#">...</a> </li>
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="#"> <i class="w-4 h-4" data-lucide="chevron-right"></i> </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="#"> <i class="w-4 h-4" data-lucide="chevrons-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <select class="w-20 form-select box mt-3 sm:mt-0">
                <option>10</option>
                <option>25</option>
                <option>35</option>
                <option>50</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- END: Pagination -->
    </div>
    <!-- BEGIN: Delete Confirmation Modal -->
    <div id="delete-confirmation-modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body p-0">
                    <div class="p-5 text-center">
                        <i data-lucide="x-circle" class="w-16 h-16 text-danger mx-auto mt-3"></i>
                        <div class="text-3xl mt-5">Are you sure?</div>
                        <div class="text-slate-500 mt-2">
                            Do you really want to delete these records?
                            <br>
                            This process cannot be undone.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="px-5 pb-8 text-center">
                        <button type="button" data-tw-dismiss="modal"
                            class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-24 mr-1">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger w-24">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END: Delete Confirmation Modal -->
    @if($modalOpen)
        @include('livewire.catalog.category-form')
    @endif

</div>
```

Esta es la vista de mi Modal:

```
<div id="category-form-modal" class="modal d-block" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog ">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- BEGIN: Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2 class="font-medium text-base mr-auto">
                    Creación de categoría
                </h2>
            </div>
            <!-- END: Modal Header -->
            <!-- BEGIN: Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body grid grid-cols-12 gap-4 gap-y-3">
                <div class="col-span-12">
                    <label for="modal-form-1" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model='name' placeholder="Nombre">
                    @error('name')
                        <small class="text-danger mt-2">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror
                </div>

                <div class="col-span-12">
                    <label for="modal-form-1" class="form-label">Descripción</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" cols="30" rows="5" wire:model='description' placeholder="Descripción de la categoría"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END: Modal Body -->
            <!-- BEGIN: Modal Footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" data-tw-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-20 mr-1">Cancelar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-20" wire:click.prevent="createCategory" data-tw-dismiss="modal" >Guardar</button>
            </div>
            <!-- END: Modal Footer -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Este es el controlador del componente:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Catalog;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Category;

class CategoryPageController extends Component
{
    public $name = 'hola';
    public $description;
    public $perPage = 20;
    public $total = 0;
    public $modalOpen = true;

    protected $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|min:4',
    ];

    protected $messages = [
        'name.required' => 'El nombre es requerido.',
        'name.min' => 'Debe tener al menos 4 letras',
    ];

    public function updated(){
        $this->validate();
    }

    public function render()
    {

        $userLogued = auth()->user();
        $companyId = $userLogued->company_id;

        $categories = Category::where('company_id', $companyId)->orderBy('name', 'DESC')->paginate(20);
        $this->total = $categories->total();

        return view('livewire.catalog.category-page-controller', [ 'categories' => $categories ])
        ->extends('layout.layout')
        ->section('content');

    }

    public function resetVariables(){
        $this->name = '';
    }

    // public function openModal(){
    //     $this->openModal = true;
    // }

    // public function closeModal(){
    //     $this->openModal = false;
    // }

    public function create(){
        $this->resetVariables();
        $this->openModal();
    }
}
```

[image: El estado normal de mi componente]

[image: Al modificar el DOM]

[image: Múltiples modals]